# Prove that two quotients of a bounded cylinder are not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, retraction

> Let $C$ be the cylinder $\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2\leq 1, |z|\leq 1\}$. Consider two relations $R$ and $R'$ on $C$ which identify a point such that $x^2+y^2=1$ with $(-x,-y,z)$ and $(-x,-y,-z)$ respectively. Show that the two quotients $C/R$ and $C/R'$ are not homeomorphic.

I tried the three classic homeomorphism invariants: connectedness, compactness (both trivially verified) and the fundamental group. It seems that the retraction of $C$ onto the two-dimensional closed disk provides a retraction of both quotients onto $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$(the disk with the well-known boundary identification).

I tried then to remove a point and check the three invariants, but it seems that connectedness is always verified and compactness never (is this all true?); and we can't take much advantage by this remarks.

Also, I have some difficulties in finding the fundamental group of the quotients without a point. This would be interesting also as a stand-alone problem.

Is there perhaps a more simple invariant? And more in general, what homeomorphism invariants are generally useful in these situations?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write $C = D^2 \times [-1,+1]$.

Before flipping through a card catalogue of invariants, it is often helpful to just try to visualize the spaces in question. Sometimes that visualization will assist you in figuring out which invariants to apply. I use the term "visualize" quite broadly. Really what I mean is simply try to analyze each space as much as you can, describe it as clearly as you can, using whatever descriptive tools you have.

Each of the spaces $C/R$ and $C/R'$ is a manifold with boundary. Furthermore, as you have noticed, each space has a natural projection to $\mathbb{P}^2$. Also, each of these projection maps is a locally trivial fiber bundle whose fiber is homeomorphic to $[-1,+1]$.

In the case of $C/R$, the fiber bundle structure is trivial. The space $C/R$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2 \times [-1,+1]$. Also, its manifold boundary $\partial(C/R)$ is the image of $D^2 \times \{-1,+1\}$. That image has two components $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \{-1\}$, $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \{1\}$, each homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$.

In the case of $C / R'$, the fiber bundle structure is nontrivial. Its boundary is also the image of $D^2 \times \{-1,+1\}$. However, in this case that image is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Another way to think of the boundaries is that the projection maps $p :C/R \to \mathbb{P}^2$ and $p' :C/R' \to \mathbb{P^2}$ each restrict to double covering maps $\partial p :\partial(C/R) \to \mathbb{P}^2$ and $\partial p' :\partial(C/R') \to \mathbb{P}^2$. The first covering map $\partial p$ is the disconnected double cover of $\mathbb{P}^2$, and the second $\partial p'$ is the orientation double cover.

Okay, enough visualization (for me, that's the fun part). Now for invariants. Any homeomorphism between manifolds with boundary restricts to a homeomorphism between the boundaries, by invariance of domain. Hence, all homeomorphism invariants of the boundary are also homeomorphism invariants of the manifold as a whole. Since the boundary of $C/R$ is disconnected whereas the boundary of $C/R'$ is connected, it follows that $C/R$ and $C/R'$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: A very useful answer, not just for this problem, thank you. How would you prove that the second boundary is homeomorphic to $S^2$? The two $S^1$ belonging to $D^2\times\{-1\}$ and to $D^2\times \{1\}$ are identified, and that should give us our statement, but since the identification is not the trivial one (it inverts orientation) should one spend some words more for the proof? Or can this be said straightforward?

Comment: It's easy enough to write down a specific formula for a homeomorphism to $S^2$: on $D^2 \times \{+1\}$ use $f(x,y) = (x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$; on $D^2 \times \{-1\}$ use $f(x,y) = (-x, -y, - \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$.

Comment: More generally, the quotient of any disjoint pair of discs using any homeomorphism between their boundaries as an identification map is homeomorphic to $S^2$.